# odoo validation error when trying to create a stock.move from onchange function

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-11, odoo-view

So i want to automatically create a move line (`move_lines`) in `stock.picking` from an `@onchange` function. Here's my function : It's just a small test. When the value of the field `changed` change, i take it as the id of the product (`product_id`) in the move line and then append that move line to the already existing list of `move_lines`.

NB1:`move_lines` is a One2many relation in `stock.picking`.
NB2:Declaration of `product_id` in `stock.move` :

```py
product_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.product', 'Product',
        domain=[('type', 'in', ['product', 'consu'])], index=True, required=True,
        states={'done': [('readonly', True)]})
```

My function :

```py
changed = fields.Integer('Changed')

@api.onchange('changed')
    def _changed_onchange(self):
        move_lines = []

        for line in self.move_lines:
            move_lines.append({'product_id': line.product_id.id or False,
                               'product_qty': line.product_qty or 0,
                               'name': line.product_id.name,
                               'product_uom': line.product_uom.id,
                               'date_planned': datetime.date.today(),
                               'date_expected': datetime.date.today()
                               })

        move_lines.append({'product_id': self.changed,
                           'name': 'default',
                           'product_uom': 1,
                           'date_planned': datetime.date.today(),
                           'date_expected': datetime.date.today()
                           })

        return {'value': {'move_lines': move_lines}}
```

If i created the move lines using the view then saved, everything works fine but when i change the value of the field so that a new move line is inserted by the function, the save doesn't work and i keep getting the error:

```
Odoo Server Error - Validation Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: product_id - product.id]
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You are passing move_lines as list of dicts which will be ignored and it will try to create moves with defaut values and resulting in 'mandatory field is not correctly set'. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To append line to `move_lines`, You can use the following syntax:

```
@api.onchange('changed')
def _changed_onchange(self):
    values = {'product_id': self.changed,
              'name': 'default',
              'product_uom': 1,
              'date_planned': datetime.date.today(),
              'date_expected': datetime.date.today(),
              'location_id': 1,
              'location_dest_id': 1
              }

    self.move_lines |= self.move_lines.create(values)
```

To achieve it using your above logic you can try [x2many values filling](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html) but I recommend you to use [Set operations](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#set-operations) and you can find an example at [Lunching wizards](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html##launching-wizards)

Comment: But that's the new element being added. self.changed is its id. i mean the for loop iterates over the existing records to keep them untouched and then add the new element which has id self.changed. even without that, i mean only keeping the for loop without the last `'product_id': self.changed` it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way how to create and then append the element ?

Comment: Check My edit (note that you should specify the mandatory fields).

Comment: I tried your method above but now its calling self.create() in the onchange function. AFAIK, it should only call self.move_lines.create() and self.create is only called after the current stock.picking is saved !!

i keep getting the error : `File "/mnt/extra-addons/stock/models/stock_picking.py", line 499, in create
    move[2]['location_id'] = vals['location_id']
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: How it calls 'self.create'?

Comment: The error comes from the create() function of stock.picking which is self.create(). I think because assigning the recordset implicitly calls create !!

Comment: No way that this code calls `create` method, debug your code to catch the piece of code that cause this issue.

Comment: You're my life savior ,i can't thank you enough ,even after all these years your answer is still useful to many people as me ,Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help